# How to add a variable to xlsxwriter .filter_column

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

Instead of hardcoding my filter I want to control it with a variable.
this works...

```
worksheet.filter_column(4, 'EXIT_HH > .4')
```

but this does not work...

```
min_hh_percent = .4
txt_min = str('EXIT_HH >' + str(min_hh_percent))
worksheet.filter_column(4, txt_min)
```

I'm getting the error "IndexError: list index out of range"

in the command line:
In: txt_min
Out: 'EXIT_HH >0.4'

In the code starting at line 757. I also removed my file path.

```
 [757] try:
        worksheet.filter_column(4, txt_min)
 except Exception as error:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

Warning: Incorrect number of tokens in criteria 'EXIT_HH >0.4'
warn("Incorrect number of tokens in criteria '%s'" % criteria)
IndexError: list index out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "...py", line 758, in 
worksheet.filter_column(4, txt_min)
File "....py", line 1727, in filter_column
tokens = self._parse_filter_expression(criteria, tokens)
File "....py", line 4019, in _parse_filter_expression
return self._parse_filter_tokens(expression, tokens)
File "...py", line 4043, in _parse_filter_tokens
token = tokens[2]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Where does the error come from? Python or Excel. If Python can you add the complete stack trace.

Comment: The error is in python, by "complete stack trace" do you want me to do a try/except with a  print(traceback.format_exc())
or
print(sys.exc_info()[2])

Comment: Just add the full error message with line numbers as output by your program.